# How to deploy elasticsearch in kubernetes established by AWS EKS

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I run elasticsearch in kubernetes cluster provided by amazon eks.

For deploy, I use [the official helm chart](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/elasticsearch).

After deploying elasticsearch pods failed on bootstrap:

```
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
```

I try to change limits.conf into a container and into an instance node. But error continues to occur.

How I can solve this issue and increase the number of max file descriptors for elasticsearch pod?

Comment: Looks pretty similar. I vote to close this question and continue to monitor that ...